# Chrome Dev Tools how to view button:hover user agent stylesheet?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools

I want to view default button element chrome user agent styles for its hover state, but when I tried to use :hover force state, nothing showed up on styles tab and the button didn't change its appearance. There's nothing for `<button>` hover state in computed styles either.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You don't need to force the state to view the property list.  All that checkbox does is force it into that state.  Perhaps the button simply doesn't have any hover-specific properties.

Comment: @LaaouatniAnas the code is simple <button>Button</button> without any custom styles. When button is hovered it changes its background-color and border-color, I wanted to know what system colors were used for that.

Comment: @sendgn do you see the visually hover effect, or not? if not maybe is the CSS doesn't get linked correctly, use `<link>` https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp . normally it should work

Comment: @sendgn here it work fine: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSDcT.png , maybe is happen because of some typo or something like that. sorry if I can't help

Comment: @LaaouatniAnas it's a standard button element without any custom styles. I see the visually hover effect, but I don't see what properties and their values were used for that in dev tools. If I use my own :hover style I see it there by clicking :hover force state btn, but when it comes to standard styles I don't see it anywhere in dev tools.

Comment: @sendgn sorry, I can't help, this seems a problem with software chrome and not the code itself,... so maybe one suggestion is to update the browser. in my case is all working https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSDcT.png

Answer (score 1):

There is no hover state provided for a button within the user agent stylesheet. In it's most basic form, a button is a rectangle with a border, which you could see when you force the :focus-visible state. The appearance of a button is controlled based on the operating system theme.

You can read about it and see the difference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/appearance).